# Blazor WebAssembly invoking protected WebAPI methods and relaying bearer token

Tags: c#, identityserver4, blazor, bearer-token

I have a restful service running on localhost:5002, Identity server on 5000 and Blazor WebAssembly app on localhost:1330. There is probably something going on with they're not all on the same domain.

I can authenticate with my Blazor WebAssembly app (Client not server) Which inturn calls WebApi methods, I get returned, 401 not authorised. I've manually added the bearer token to the requests and it works perfectly returning results etc.

```
HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "{{BEARER TOKEN VALUE}}");
```

My main question is. What's the best way to get the Bearer token and pass it on?

Answer (score 2):

IMO the best way is to use the `IHttpClientFactory` and assign the token by using the built-in `BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler`

**Setup DI**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>(options =>
                {
                    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId= "{YOUR CLIENT ID}";                                    
                    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri= "http://localhost:1330/authentication/login-callback";
                })
                .AddHttpClient("apiClient")
                .ConfigureHttpClient(httpClient =>
                {
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = "http://localhost:5002";
                })
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Use in Component or Service by injecting an `IHttpClientFactory`

**Component Sample**

```cs
@inject IHttpClientFactory _factory
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient("apiClient")
        var data = await client.GetJsonAsync<Data>("api/data");
    }
}
```

There is multiple way to use `IHttpClientFactory`, read [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. What references are you using? 
When I add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication` I get 'IRemoteAuthenticationBuilder<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>' does not contain a definition for 'AddHttpClient' and no accessible extension method 'AddHttpClient'

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` 3.1.3

Comment: hmm,  It appears there might be some breaking changes ahead. 
I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=3.2.0.0,

I can't see any signatures matching AddOidcAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>?
I get this compile-time exception 
'IRemoteAuthenticationBuilder<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount>' does not contain a definition for 'AddHttpClient' and the best extension method overload 'HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHttpClient(IServiceCollection, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IServiceCollection'

Comment: Ahh, I think it was because I was missing .Services in your example 
.Services.AddHttpClient("apiClient")
However, I still get a 401 when calling the client?

Comment: Check your log and settings